group data and remove duplicate
I have the data in the form of table below
Name     Mas       Sce
   M      ( (87)    83
            (91)    
          (97) )    
   T        (77)    76
   R        (60)    32
   G        (95)    20
   M     ( (50)     89
            (50)    
          (99) )    

Some of my data runs through multiple row such as M case. The data is enclosed within the bracket
I have tried drop duplicates. It works when its single row. But, now i have a few rows as a group
import pandas as pd

d = {'Name': ['M', None, None, 'T', 'R', 'G', 'M', '', ''],
     'Mas': ['( (87)', '(91)', '(97) )', '(77)', '(60)', '(95)', '( (50)', '(50)', '(99) )'],
     'Sce': ['83', '', '', '76', '32', '20', '89', '', '']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['Name'] = df['Name'].ffill()
print(df)
df.drop_duplicates(subset='Name', keep='first', inplace=True)
print(df)

I want to remove reoccurence of the data. In this case, the 2nd M
Name     Mas       Sce
   M      ( (87)    83
            (91)    
          (97) )    
   T        (77)    76
   R        (60)    32
   G        (95)    20


I'm not sure I understand the details. Why does the input data have None in some spots and null strings in others? Null strings don't get ffilled. Secondly, why aren't you removing the parentheses? The Mas data should ultimately be int, no? Thirdly, don't you want to ffill Sce too?

And shouldn't Name be ffilled in the result?

"runs through multiple columns" - you meant rows? Do you want to keep it that way? Your take is intuitively right, but it would require collapsing empty name rows into rows above.

@wjandrea its from some input. The parentheses which i thought it is useful for some pattern filtering but apparently not needed. Mas data is in string. Sce shall remain as is. Name not ffilled

@GeorginaSkibinski corrected. Thats the part i am having the problem

A pure pandas one-liner with duplicated, a mask and ffill:
out = df[~df['Name'].duplicated()
          .mask(df['Name'].replace('', None).isna())
          .ffill().infer_objects(copy=False)]

Output:
   Name     Mas Sce
0     M  ( (87)  83
1  None    (91)    
2  None  (97) )    
3     T    (77)  76
4     R    (60)  32
5     G    (95)  20


Try:
# make the `Name` column consistent -> change  "", None to NaNs
df["Name"] = np.where(df["Name"].isin(["", None]), np.nan, df["Name"])

# create a mask what to keep and what to discard
mask = ~(
    pd.Series(
        np.where(df["Name"].notna(), df["Name"].duplicated(keep="first"), np.nan),
        index=df.index,
    )
    .ffill()
    .astype(bool)
)

# print final df
print(df[mask])

Prints:
  Name     Mas Sce
0    M  ( (87)  83
1  NaN    (91)    
2  NaN  (97) )    
3    T    (77)  76
4    R    (60)  32
5    G    (95)  20


Should note you're skipping OP's ffill

@wjandrea I think this is the attempt that OP tried and it didn't work (I'm supposing the first dataframe OP has shown is the input).

Ah yeah, fair enough. I just assumed cause I always print(df) immediately after constructing it. I had edited the code like that but I'll edit it back.

You can avoid np.where with the Pandas equivalents: df["Name"].mask(df["Name"].isin(["", None])) and df["Name"].duplicated(keep="first").where(df["Name"].notna()) (which also lets you avoid .astype(bool)).
